# How to password protect printing on a HP Officejet?

Tags: security, printing, printer, network-printer

We discovered that our HP Officejet 6700 was directly accessible from the internet after someone printed a pamphlet about 'Serpent People in New York' (quite hilarious actually).

Ofcourse, we'd like to prevent this from happening again. However, I quite like the 'printing from the internet'-feature (so that I can print stuff when away from home).

Is it possible to somehow add some protection to printing? E.g. a password that each computer should have, a SSL-certificate I have to install, ... ?

I have a few Windows machines and one linux machine that will print regularly to this machine from the local network, and one linux machine that will most often print via the internet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Set up a [VPN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_network) and make the printer visible only inside it.

This way, every device connected to the VPN will be able to see and use the printer. Outside the VPN, the printer or any other network resources won't be accessible.

I'm always recommending to never expose these network devices publicly. Exposure might look handy at the beginning but this does not go together with privacy expectation you expressed in your comment above.

I know this is not a direct answer, but it actually "password-protects" your network including your printer.

Comment: His printer isnt in a DMZ, its web enabled.  A VPN wouldnt do anything in this situation

Comment: @Keltari – sorry I meant simple VPN without DMZ. Where you just log in from the PC and see all the devices. I meant keeping it simple.

Comment: That could indeed fix it, together with a decent firewall setup. Solid advice

Answer (score 1):

Your HP ePrint account can be set to accept print documents only from some
specified email accounts. Currently it may be set to accept from everyone.

This is a weak security measure, but may be enough
to prevent 'Serpent People in New York' from printing again.

References :

- [HP Connected](https://www.hpconnected.com)
- [HP Printers - Turning On Web Services](https://support.hp.com/us-en/document/c05329102)
- [Introduction to HP Web Services](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4lS8e_27kiE)
  (video)

Comment: If I'm right, this involves sending the documents first to HP, which will relay them to my printer? Not really privacy friendly...

Comment: It might already be set, and the prankster might be one of your colleagues. You may turn it off entirely if that's the case.

Comment: An admin password was set on the printer, a manual factory reset fixed that. And it is a home printer, I don't think my mom or dad printed that.